# What are the limits of what we should try to learn?

Tags: pirke-avot-ethicsof, adult-learning, chinuch-education

In the Mishnah, Ben Zoma famously said:

> אֵיזֶהוּ חָכָם, הַלּוֹמֵד מִכָּל אָדָם -- Who is wise? He who learns from every man. [Avot 4:1]

What does it mean?

(1) That every individual who enters your life, in person or from afar, has something useful to teach you.

(2) That you should go out of your way to seek out people, especially people who are very different from you, because they know some wisdom you don't know.

Most people would say (1).  But is (2) to be rejected out of hand?  Should you try to learn, say, about other religions, other cultures, in case their different point of view might add positively to yours?  The danger is that they may lead you astray, and you may not know enough to take the good and reject the bad.

In the Talmud, God refuses to quote the opinions of Rabbi Meir because Rabbi Meir learned from Acher, the heretic.  Then a rabbi told God there is nothing wrong with taking the good and rejecting the bad, as Meir did.  God accepts that teaching and starts quoting Rabbi Meir. [Ḥagigah 15b] (One of the many times God is "taught" and accepts the teaching saying, "לִמַּדְתַּנִי – *Lamadtani!* You have taught Me!" [see, e.g., Numbers Rabbah 19:33].)

Rabbi Meir knew how to recognize the good from the bad, but you and I may not.  So is my (2) out of the question?  But that situation would occur also in my (1).  So what is the resolution?  How far should one go in trying to "learn from every person"?

Comment: What about (3) Not everyone necessarily has something to teach you, nor do you need to go seeking teachings from everyone, but if someone does have something to teach you you should be willing to learn it from him regardless of who he is?

Comment: Premise contradicts Ben Zoma, but possible alternative.

Comment: "But is (2) to be rejected out of hand?" I am not following this. What makes you think (2) is wrong, much less "out of hand"?

Comment: Why can't they both be applicable?

Comment: @dov. 1 is contained in 2.

Comment: @MichoelR.  2 requires you to investigate systems that are very far from Judaism so you can extract useful wisdom from them.

Comment: I think it means being open to learn from everyone you come across, not that you have to learn everything at all possible.